# MERGE en PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql

Estoy intentanto hacer un `MERGE` en PostgreSQL 9.5 y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MERGE"
LINE 1: MERGE INTO TP_ESTADO_EQUIPOS AS EQ
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "MERGE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

**SQL**

```
MERGE INTO TP_ESTADO_EQUIPOS AS EQ
USING (SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE_STATE_EQUIPMENT) AS VEQ
ON EQ.ESTADO_EQUIPOS_ID = VEQ.ESTADO_EQUIPO_ID
 WHEN MATCHED THEN (
 EQ.TIEMPO_INICIO=VEQ.TIEMPO_INICIO,
 EQ.TIEMPO_FIN=VEQ.TIEMPO_FIN,
 ...
 )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(Estado_Equipos_ID,
        Tiempo_Inicio,
        ...
        )
        VALUES(VEQ.ESTADO_EQUIPO_ID,
                VEQ.Tiempo_Inicio,
                ...);
```

He estado leyendo documentación, y posiblemente tenga que usar 'UPSERT', pero aun no me queda muy claro si es ese necesariamente el error. Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El UPSERT consiste en hacer un insert común, pero incluyendo un ON CONFLICT para indicar el campo o los campos que no pueden repetirse y luego un DO UPDATE SET para asignar las columnas con los nuevos valores que serán asignados si ya existe un registro con el mismo campo(s) indicado(s) en el ON CONFLICT.

```
INSERT INTO TP_ESTADO_EQUIPOS 
(SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE_STATE_EQUIPMENT) 
 ON CONFLICT (estado_equipos_id)
 DO UPDATE SET 
 TIEMPO_INICIO=EXCLUDED.TIEMPO_INICIO,
 ... ;
```

Comment: Gracias amigo desconocido XD